# Initialize module python

Tags: python, module, initialization

I have a [module](https://github.com/rtaycher/second_hand_songs_wrapper) which wrap an json api for querying song cover/remix data with limits for number of requests per hour/minute. I'd like to keep an optional cache of json responses without forcing users to adjust a cache/context parameter every time. What is a good way of initializing a library/module in python? Or would you recommend I just do the explicit thing and use a cache named parameter in every call that eventually request json data?

I was thinking of doing

```
_cache = None

class LFU(object):
    ...

NO_CACHE, LFU = "NO_CACHE", "LFU"
def set_cache_strategy(strategy):
    if _cache == NO_CACHE:
        _cache = None
    else:
        _cache = LFU()
```

---

```
import second_hand_songs_wrapper as s
s.set_cache_strategy(s.LFU)
l1 = s.ShsLabel.get_from_resource_id(123)
l2 = s.ShsLabel.get_from_resource_id(123,use_cache=Fale)
```

edit:
I'm probably only planning on having two strategies one with/ one without a cache.

Other possible alternative initialization schemes I can think of of the top of my head include using enviromental variables, initializing _cache by hand in the user code to None/LFU(), and using explicit cache everywhere(possibly defaulting to having a cache).

Note the reason I don't set cache on an instance of the class is that I currently use a never instantiated class(use class functions + class state as a singleton) to abstract downloading the json data along with some convenience/methods to download certain urls. I could instantiate the downloader class but then I'd have to pass the instance explicitly to each function, or use another global variable for a convenience version of the class. The downloader class also keeps track of # of requests(website has limit per minute/hour) so having multiple downloader objects would cause more trouble.

Comment: Why don't you configure the caching strategy on an instance of a class rather than on the module?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in setting a default, even if that default is `None`.  I would note though that having the pseudo-constants as well as a conditional (provided that's all you use the values for) is redundant.  Try:

```
caching_strategies = {'NO_CACHE' : lambda: None,
                      'LFU' : LFU}
_cache = caching_strategies['NO_CACHE']

def set_cache_strategy(strategy):
    _cache = caching_methods[strategy]()
```

If you want to provide a convenience method for the available strategies, just wrap `caching_strategies.keys()`.  Really though, as far as your strategies go, you should probably have all your strategies inherit from some base strategy, and just create a no_cache strategy class that inherits from that and stubs all the methods for your standardized caching inteface.